# TeamCity build error MSB3202 can't find file csproj

Tags: build, teamcity, csproj, agent

Get error then i run build:

```
[dotnet build] in directory: /opt/buildagent/work/d19a958ec8a4811c
[08:40:52]  [dotnet build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET
[08:40:52]  [dotnet build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[08:40:52]  [dotnet build] 
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100/NuGet.targets(289,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/buildagent/work/d19a958ec8a4811c/src/Vismo/Vismo.csproj" was not found.
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] 
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] Build FAILED.
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] 
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build]     0 Warning(s)
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build]     1 Error(s)
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] 
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] Time Elapsed 00:00:01.60
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] Process exited with code 1
[08:40:54]  [dotnet build] Process exited with code 1 (Step: Build .NET (.NET))
```

But in agent dir this file i find:

```
root@345d573c963:/# find / -name Vismo.csproj
/opt/buildagent/work/d19a958ec8a4811c/src/Vismo/Vismo.csproj
```

I am doing something wrong? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: How is the build step configured in TC?

Comment: Build .NET - Command "build" - Projects "src/PROJ.sln" - Framework "netcoreapp3.1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above example is incorrect. VIsmo, not Vismo.
I'm missing a big letter